# Adding spamassassin to postfix causes sender_bcc emails to triplicate

Tags: postfix, dovecot, spamassassin

I have had a well working postfix/dovecot mail installation at home for a couple of years.  To ensure all outgoing mail gets saved, I have  `sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_bcc` in my `main.cf` file

There are entries in that map file of the form
`alan@myemaildomain alan+saveout@save.save`.

There are entries in /etc/postfix/transport of the form
`save.save   lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp`

And dovecot has a sieve file which is processed first with the following

`require ["fileinto", "envelope", "subaddress","date","mailbox","variables"];
if envelope :detail "to" "saveout"{
 if currentdate :matches "year" "*" { set "year" "${1}"; }
 if currentdate :matches "month" "*" { set "month" "${1}"; }
 fileinto :create "Sent/${year}/${month}";
 stop;
}`

My wife was moaning that too much spam was coming through (I have been also using `dspam` between `postfix` and `dovecot` but I think its been fairly untouched for a while) so I decided to add `spamassassin` using the recommended approach of adding it as a content filter to incoming messages to
the `master.cf` file in postfix, ie changing the first line to

`smtp      inet  n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
    -o content_filter=spamassassin`
 
and adding at the end of this file

`spamassassin unix - n   n   -   -   pipe
  user=debian-spamd argv=/usr/bin/spamc -f -e /usr/sbin/sendmail -G -oi -f ${sender} ${recipient}`

Now everytime I send an e-mail I get three copies of it in my sent-mail folder (obviously previously it worked with just putting the one there).

I am both trying to get my head around why I should suddenly get three copies.  I suspect that something to do with spamassassin getting invoked for the send to `alan_saveout@save.save` in some way, and postfix adding ANOTHER sender_bcc entry.

Has anyone else experience this, and what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that e-mail to @save.save was also passing through.  In the end I dropped this version of calling `spamassassin` and installed `spamass-milter` instead.  All working well.

I also took the opportunity to tighten up milter-greylist to greylist more stuff.